# Is there a way to do this in one SELECT statement? Using Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, table 1. In this table is name, city, price. The names are all unique, the cities can be reused. I want to make a query that gives me the highest price of each city, and the name associated with that row. To get the highest price of each city I just do:

```
SELECT MAX(price), city FROM table1 GROUP BY city
```

But I want the name as well. If I try

```
SELECT MAX(price), city, name FROM table1 GROUP BY city
```

Then I just get a query error about how name isn't included in the group by. If I add name to the group by, then it doesn't do what I want. I can think of how I could do this using two queries, but I bet there's a way to do it in just one. What am I missing?

I've found a few similar questions on stackoverflow, but they all seem to be doing something more complicated than I'm attempting to. I've only ever used simple SQL queries, so I'm educating myself on some of the more advanced features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH RankedPrices AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY price DESC) AS ix
    FROM table1
)
SELECT * FROM RankedPrices WHERE ix=1;
```

Note that you didn't specify what should happen if two products in a city are both the most expensive and equal in their price. This query here returns any of the two (but only one), you could also handle this differently.

Comment: Yes this seems to come back down to me not knowing exactly what I want (or more specifically, using an old database table to try out some new queries). The other answers give me repeats. I only sort of understand how your query functions, but in a day I should have it. Thanks

Comment: I split the query in two steps: first I rank the prices partitioned by city in the "virtual table" (the name for that construct is a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)), so that I known which is the most expensive item by its rank (`ix`). I then filter by this. So if you wanted the first three most expensive names per city, you could just do `ix<=3` in the where clause. Or if you want different ranking, just use another of the [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) provided by SQL Server instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: I sort of understand, could I ask a few questions in chat?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  name, city, price
FROM
  table1 t
WHERE
  price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM table 1 WHERE city = t.city)
```

An index over `(city, price)` and one over `(price)` helps the performance of this query if there are many rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, city, price
FROM table1 t
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM table1 WHERE city = t.city)
```

Comment: This did work, sort of. It gives me multiple rows with the same city if the prices are the same. I guess group by only gives you the first? I'm not quite sure how your query is doing what it does though. Is price being recalculated for each city or something? Obviously (SELECT MAX(price) FROM table1 WHERE city = t.city) isn't just returning a single number, but I'm not sure how

Comment: @cost, the problem with `GROUP BY` is that it aggregates, so that it computes something from multiple row values, but you don't know what the original rows were. That's why none of the solutions here used `GROUP BY` (even though the conceptually same approach as for this sample could be achieved by using a `JOIN` on a `GROUP BY` nested query).

Comment: @cost, yes, the price is being recalculated for each city. The query finds the name and city where the price is the maximum for that particular city. Are the multiple rows returning the same name? Or just the same city?

Comment: @LoganSerman The multiple rows have the same city, and that's just because of bad data. I feel like I'm missing something in understanding how this works though, I'm still very new to SQL. If I just run (SELECT MAX(price) FROM table1 WHERE city = t.city) then it just returns one number, the highest price of any of the cities. What is happening different in the complete query that's making it all work?

Comment: Imagine the query iterating through each row in your database. On a particular row, the query wants to determine if it should include that row as part of it's result set, and if should include it, it will return the `name`, `city`, and `price`. But when should it include it? From the `WHERE` clause, it should include it when the `price` of that row is equal to the maximum `price` across all rows of that same city. The subquery in the `WHERE` clause will return a different value for each city in the database, and that value will be the maximum price for that particular city.

Comment: Think about the query in English: "retrieve the name, city, and price of any row where the price of that row is maximum price for it's city".

Answer (score 1):

**Just for completeness**, here's a sample using `GROUP BY`, but with the same caveats as the other solutions by Tomalak and Logan in regards of handling duplicate max prices per city:

```
SELECT t2.city, t2.name, t2.price
    FROM (SELECT city, MAX(price) AS price FROM table1 GROUP BY city) AS t
    JOIN table1 AS t2 ON t.city = t2.city AND t.price = t2.price
```

I prefer the ranking approach because it is clearer and much more flexible.